# How to redirect output to /dev/null or a txt file

Tags: shell

I get these messages as part of output even after redirection to /dev/null or a txt file, anyway to avoid these?

```
./a.txt: line 44: opatch: command not found
./a.txt: line 44: /dev/null: Permission denied
grep: /ContentsXML/inventory.xml: No such file or directory
```

The redirection not working.
Here's the code

```
inventory_dir=`opatch lsinventory |grep -i 'Central Inventory' | cut -d ":" -f2` 2>&1 /dev/null
```

Comment: `opatch: command not found` means the shell couldn't find the command called `opatch` which means your PATH doesn't include the place where `opatch` resides. Your options are 1) to put `opatch` somewhere in your PATH, 2) to change your PATH to include wherever `opatch` resides, or 3) use the full path to `opatch` every time you want to run it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks, But is there a way to avoid displaying this in output? somehow

Comment: You can use something like this `command >/dev/null 2>&1` , it will sends standard output and all the error messages to the null device

Comment: @SyedSaadAhmed Tried it, still displaying ' cmd not found'. Thanks anyways :))

Comment: Just to make sure, because what's SyedSaadAhmed said was right, when you say you've tried it, are talking about your code example ? Because, in that code you're not redirecting to /dev/null, you're trying to execute it, hence the Permission denied you see in your output...you're missing ">" and typically that redirection should be before "2>&1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirections of a command do not apply to the substitutions in that command.

You can instead wrap it all in `{ ..; }` and redirect that:

```
{
  inventory_dir=`opatch lsinventory |grep -i 'Central Inventory' | cut -d ":" -f2`
} 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

USE THIS    inventory_dir=`opatch lsinventory |grep -i 'Central Inventory' | cut -d ":" -f2` > output.txt or >>